# AndroidX WorkManager - "how to" make a scheduled job persistent?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have followed the guidelines from googles codelabs regarding the implementation of a WorkManager and scheduling of a job.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(Is30DaysOldWorker.class, PERIODIC_WORKREQUEST_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                       .addTag(IS_30_DAYS_OLD_WORKER)
                                       .build();
getWorkManager().enqueue(workRequest);
```

From the google [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) the `WorkManager` uses a `JobScheduler` for API 23+ (my case) - so is it possible make the scheduled job persistent after a device restart?

In a `JobScheduler` scenario you would normally do it by specifying a `JobInfo.setPersisted(true)` flag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went through the documentation it is not mentioned that `WorkManager` will handle persisted `WorkRequests` although as you said that `JobInfo` already has that flag.

However in the source there is method named `rescheduleEligibleWork()`, which reschedules all jobs upon boot or similar cases. It stores the work requests in its own room database.

```
/**
     * Reschedules all the eligible work. Useful for cases like, app was force stopped or
     * BOOT_COMPLETED, TIMEZONE_CHANGED and TIME_SET for AlarmManager.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
    public void rescheduleEligibleWork() {
        // Reset scheduled state.
        getWorkDatabase().workSpecDao().resetScheduledState();

        // Delegate to the WorkManager's schedulers.
        // Using getters here so we can use from a mocked instance
        // of WorkManagerImpl.
        Schedulers.schedule(getWorkDatabase(), getSchedulers());
    }
```

There is no way specified how to configure it to act upon such cases in the doc.
Since `WorkManagerImpl` constructor uses `Context` that (probably) means that if your application has permission to `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, the `WorkManager` will receive this event and reschedule all work requests that hasn't been executed within given window you have specified in the `Work.Builder`.

Comment: `WorkManager` fires all the pending `WorkRequest`s even without `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission, just tested.